# Einstein's original papers predicting gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, experimental-technique, interferometry, ligo

I came across the original handwritten papers in which Einstein predicted gravitational waves<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

and since [LIGO announced they've detected a signal](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2016/feb/11/ligo-detects-first-ever-gravitational-waves-from-two-merging-black-holes) confirming the predictions I was wondering if someone can briefly describe the equations and possibly explain the mechanism of the experiment?

---

<sup>1. Full original manuscript http://alberteinstein.info/vufind1/Digital/EAR000000025#page/1/mode/1up</sup>

Comment: Does the picture of the document make this question more clear?

Comment: @DanielSank If you would like I could use the text editor to rewrite the field equation for clarity, as for the picture, I think it provides sufficient context for the question.

Comment: Do you happen to have a higher resolution version of that page? And could you give us some links to where you got it? Thank you :-)

Comment: @GiorgioComitini Here is the full manuscript: http://alberteinstein.info/vufind1/Digital/EAR000000025#page/35/mode/1up

Comment: Great, thank you! I may be able to explain the mathematics of gravitational waves (though I need to consult the manuscript in order to follow Einstein's notation). I'll see what I can do.

Comment: DanielSank's point is that the picture of the handwriting and the field equation are wholly irrelevant to asking how the LIGO experiment works

Comment: Thanks, @ACuriousMind, for yet again articulating my thoughts clearly :D

Comment: @ACuriousMind you both guys are missing the tags that clearly mark: _general relativity_ (referring to the predicting equations) and _interferometry_ (referring the experimental set-up). I think, that is clear to everyone that a single page couldn't provide explanation for gravitational waves.

Comment: What? I understand the question and the tags perfectly fine. The picture just doesn't add anything of value to your actual question: *"I was wondering if someone can briefly describe the equations and possibly explain the mechanism of the experiment"*

Comment: @ACuriousMind that is great, in that case you can just ignore it. :)

Comment: Put the link in the question - comments are more volatile and it saves people digging through them

Comment: It might interest you to learn that at one point in time Einstein actually believed he proved that gravitational waves could not exist in GR: http://www.geology.cwu.edu/facstaff/lee/courses/g503/Einstein_review.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The paper referred to above as the "Full original manuscript" is the "Die Grundlagen der allgemeinen Relativitatstheorie" paper - the original paper on General Relativity published in March 1916 in Annalen der Physik.  As far as I know that makes no reference to gravitational waves.  The first of Einstein's papers to explicitly refer to Gravitational waves was "Naherungsweise Integration der Feldgleichungen der Gravitation" published a few months later in May 1916 in the Sitzung of the Prussian Academy (pp 688-696):
http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/get_file?pdfs/SPAW./1916/1916SPAW.......688E.pdf
(See the very last page.)

However, that paper was flawed and Einstein had to write THE paper on gravitational waves: "Uber Gravitationswellen", published in February 1918 in the same journal (pp.154-167). (See Steinicke, "Einstein and the gravitational waves", @Astron. Nach. 2005  vol. 326, p640).

What happened next when in 1937 he wrote the paper with Rosen is well documented in the paper by Kennefick referred to above by @Dargscisyhp.

Much of this reflects the difficulty people had in coming to terms with the incredible coordinate freedom that General Relativity had to offer.  Even interpreting something as simple as de Sitter's metric caused long-term confusion, particularly with regard to the question of the red-shift. GR is a wonderful theory, albeit somewhat abstruse and even, at times, abstruse for its great inventor!

Comment: around the last event, I heard that it was a 1911 or 1912 paper, published before the GR

Comment: I'd heard that too but could not trace a reference.  The first version of GR was the Einstein-Grossmann "Entwurf" paper of 1913 (Zeit. Math. Phys. **62**, 1-38.  This was the paper written in Zurich at the time Einstein was learning about Riemannian Geometry (see the Zurich notebook) and gave vacuum field equations.  So it's hard to imagine anything before that coming up with gravitational waves as we understand them now.  The "Entwurf" equations were in fact solved in 1914 by Droste, a student of Lorentz, to give the Schwarzschild solution (Kon. Ned. Akad. Weten. Ser. B. **17**, 998-1011)!

Comment: Isn't it true that Einstein didn't predict gravitational waves, but argued with Rosen that they don't exist?

Comment: As I said, the story is in Kennefick's paper, Physics Today, 2005, 58, 43. But that is not open access.  So, briefly, Einstein and Rosen did submit a paper saying that gravitational waves did not exist.  Robertson found an error and rejected the paper.  Einstein got annoyed and resubmitted to the J. Franklin Institute.  While correcting proofs, Infeld, his research assistant explained Robertson's critique to Einstein.  Einstein corrected the paper thanking Robertson.  Ironically, Rosen submitted what must have been the original paper to a Russian journal - Einstein was not a co-author on that.